# generic 71 key "60 Percent" keyboard layout

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I have a desktop using Debian 11 Bullseye with a 71 button keyboard and no individual F1..12 keys (they are combined with the top row and activated with by pressing the `Fn` key as the shifter, in combination with a top row key.  It only has 5 rows of keys and no separate keypad.  The only major problem is not being able to change between TTY consoles.

My keyboard layout doesn't appear to be available under Debian's KDE "Input Devices" >  "Keyboard" > "Hardware" [ "Keyboard model"] dropdown list.  I'm using "Generic | Generic 101-key PC" from the dropdown list.  (I've never heard of this brand before, but there are no keyboard "generic" types that are explicitly named for less than 101 keys.  Mine has 71)

My major problem is that I can't change between TTY consoles using `ctrl`- `alt` - `F1..7` key combination press, and the `Fn` doesn't help out if I add it to the combination.  The `F1..12` keys all work as I expect in Vim, when I press in combination with the `Fn` shifter key.

However, I can't switch between TTY consoles.  Is there a layout in Debian Bullseye for keyboards without independent function keys that would be better.  Especially a layout that would allow me to swith between TTYs?  Or should I look into keyboard mappings and try to figure out how to map that behavior?  Or should I write a startup.sh file that runs a macro that's available from any TTY?